# Kohana routing external url

Tags: url, routes, kohana

I want to have url like this in my application
http://website.com/click/http://google.com

with

```
Route::set('click', 'click(/<action>(/<link>))', array('link' =>'[\w\d-_/:]+'))
        ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'admanager',
        'action' => 'index',
    ));
```

but it does't work with http:// but works when omitting http:// from the url

Please advice,
Thanks
Abbas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to base64 encode that. Putting a raw url inside a url (see the problem? :) will never work very well.